# Help finding a Sci-fi Novel with a "Communist" Aesthetic

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember most vividly the novels cover being very "communist" (or totalitarian) in design. Faux Pseudo Cyrillic, red and black color scheme. The book itself to the best of my memory was about a series of (post apoc?) city states in a vague slavic iceland connected by a railroad. The book also had a map in the same black red color scheme inside. I remember seeing it on the shelves at Barnes and Noble.
 Edit: I have a lead, the Wolfhound Century Series, if it isn't that its definitely in its vein.

The most defining feature to restate was the black, red and maybe white map inside the book showing the various city states and there connecting railways

Comment: Can you narrow down a time frame? At first I thought maybe the Chung Kuo novels by David Wingrove as the original covers had a cover design somewhat similar to what you describe but I can't confirm the map, which would probably DQ that series.

Comment: Definitely published late 2000's early 2010's, i saw it at barnes and noble 3, 4 years ago?

Comment: If the Wolfhound Century Series turned out to be it, you can post it as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

### Metro 2035

This is a link to volume 3 of the **Metro 203*** trilogy: [https://www.amazon.com/METRO-English-language-Dmitry-Glukhovsky/dp/1539930726/ref=as_li_ss_tl?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1481305449&sr=1-1&keywords=metro+2035&linkCode=sl1&tag=sciandscabo0a-20&linkId=113927486a7821ac3aa4595ad4e0f790](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1539930726)

Volumes 1 and 2 are **Metro 2033** and **Metro 2034**.

Volume 3 has a map of the Moscow Metro, the former stations now being independent city states. It's post-apocalyptic in a sense that a certain state of stability has been achieved after the initial apocalyptic events.

I cannot, however, confirm the "communist aesthetics". It could, however, be a different edition with a different cover. After all, the series is based on the computer game **Metro 2033**, which features a definitive "communist aesthetic": https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_2033_(Computerspiel) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_2033_(video_game)

Comment: I am familiar with this series and it is not this for sure.